# Who _____ that handsome Young man and his friend?

Tags: word-choice, singular-vs-plural, coordination

Who _____ that handsome Young man and his friend?

1)is

2)was

3)had been

4)are

5)has been

which one should I use and why? Thank you.

I Think number 1 is the correct one. The word 'that' made me come to this conclusion.

Comment: You should say which one you think is correct, and why you think it might not be!

Comment: I Think number 1 is the correct one. The word 'that' made me come to this conclusion.

Comment: Any of these can be correct, depending on the context. Please [edit](http://ell.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/34964) your post to explain the situation you are trying to describe, and what *you* believe the correct answer is and why.

Answer (score 2):

> Who _____ that handsome Young man and his friend?

"that handsome Young man and his friend" are two persons then you need a plural verb. (4) "are" or (3) "had been" are correct.

When you see "**and**" between two single nouns, it makes them plural.

> Sara and Nima **are** good people.
>
> That man and this woman **are engaged**.